# how to access a variable from a .php file which is entered in another .php file?

Tags: php, html, mysql

My question is that i enter a value in a text field (field name = usn) in my_file.php file. Now i want to access the value usn that is entered in demo file from another file say demo.php.

I have several files and i don't want to use text fields every time to access this value. 
This should be accessible from all files whenever I want.

In the following example the value usn should be accessible from another file without reentering it.

```
$que_ccodes = "INSERT INTO ec_course_codes ( usn, cc1, cc2, cc3, cc4, cc5, cc6 ) 
    VALUES ( :usn, :cc1, :cc2, :cc3, :cc4, :cc5, :cc6 )";
        $query_params1 = array( ':usn' => $_POST['usn'], ':cc1' => $_POST['cc1'], ':cc2' => $_POST['cc2'], ':cc3' => $_POST['cc3'], ':cc4' => $_POST['cc4'], ':cc5' => $_POST['cc5'], ':cc6' => $_POST['cc6']);
        $statement1 = $db->prepare($que_ccodes);
        $result1 = $statement1->execute($query_params1);
```

Comment: `$_SESSION`: http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Comment: PHP is a server-side language. As long as you do not request demo.php, you will not get what the user enters. In demo.php it will be in `$_REQUEST` after requesting it.

Comment: at the very top of your file include previous file `include("my_file")`

Comment: so what i am going to do.. in my_file....session_start(); $_session['usn']; include("demo.php");... and then in demo.php...what to write

Comment: yes I need to include it in demo.php...if not please tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments have already told that, but this is an example.

You should store the value where you receive it at first place:

```
session_start();

$your_var = "my value";

$_SESSION['session_name'] = $your_var;
```

And for getting it in other scripts you can do this:

```
$my_var = "empty";

if(isset($_SESSION['session_name']))
{
  $my_var = $_SESSION['session_name'];
}
```

There are some tips about using sessions that you should check before getting really deep into them. For example you can't use sessions over different domain names. Your session id would be available only under the domain that it has been created.

Check this:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Comment: for the first file i got error.... Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in....

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with sessions so you might want to check your other parts of the code for correction, and there is nothing obvious from this error that you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

You should use include()

index.php:

```
<?php
    include("otherfile.php");
?>
```

and all the variables from otherfile.php will be accessible in index.php